# Passing functions between components

Tags: angular, angular9

I am having trouble passing a function between the three components. Simplified, the situation looks like this:
I have a parent component in which a function will be supported, e.g.

*parent.ts*

```
goToHomePage() { console.log('homepage') }
```

*parent.html*

```
<nb-tabs>
  (actionButton)="goToHomePage()"
</nb-tabs>
```

Then component Tabs is the parent child and it has another TAB component inside to which I want to pass the parent function.

*tabs.html*

```
<nb-tab
    [actionButton]="actionButton"
 ></nb-tab>
```

and *Tab.html*

```
<div class="tab">
    <button
      (click)="onclick()"
    >Next</button>
  </div>
```

*Tab.ts*

```
  public actionButton: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onclick(){
    this.actionButton.emit();
  }
```

However, it doesn't work, I don't know how to pass functions through three components (parent -> child -> child), so far I've only done two components (parent -> child). Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: looks like the "react" way of doing things. Why u dont just create a service provide it on the parent component and use DI to resolve the Service in your child-components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `actionButton`as an `Output()` in tabs and tab components like this:

```
@Output()
actionButton: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

parent.html

```
<nb-tabs (actionButton)="goToHomePage()"></nb-tabs>
```

tabs.html

```
<nb-tab
    (actionButton)="onActionButtonEmitted()"
 ></nb-tab>
```

tabs.ts

```
onActionButtonEmitted(): void {
  this.actionButton.emit();
}
```

Tab.ts

```
 actionButton: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  onclick(){
    this.actionButton.emit();
  }
```